How to show Sharepoint list calculated column in combo box?
In my Canvas app, I have a combo box that binds to a Sharepoint list calculated column calculatedColA.
Sharepoint list myList calculatedColA = TEXT([DateCol],"yyyymmd")&" "&[ColB]
When I run it, it doesn't show list of values for calculatedColA.
How can I show calculatedColA values in myList ?
Thank you

You just need to change the items property of your combo box to YourListName.calculatedColA.
Here is my test result:
combox box:

Result:

List:


Thank you so much for your help
